# c# string is interrupting foreach

Tags: c#, string, sockets, foreach

I have a Projekt that uses Socket to send and recive data of a 2D game.
The game client has to send his nickname to the server where the nickname is stored in gamer.name. All the gamers are stored in a list `List<Gamer>`.

So when a client requests the list of users the server sends a string composed by `Send(socket, "01$" + gamer.id.ToString() + "$" + gamer.name + "$" + gamer.in_game.ToString())`

- 01 tells the client that the following data is user data
- gamer.id is the id of a client
- gamer.name the name
- gamer.in_game is true if the gamer is playing

But when the client recives the string all the data after gamer.name is gone. So I tried to output the same data in a MessageBox (on the server programm) and there the data after gamer.name was also gone (so its not a Socket problem).

I tought well than I just have to change the position of gamer.name to the end of the string.
(`Send(socket, "01$" + gamer.id.ToString() + "$" + gamer.in_game.ToString() + "$" + gamer.name);`)

But the problem was not solved because `Send(socket, "01...` is running in a `foreach(Gamer gamer in users)` and the string gamer.name like stopped the foreach and so the server instead of sending all users it just sends the first and then the foreach is interrupted by gamer.name .

How is it possible that a string can break a foreach and how can I fix it?

The code that stores the username:

```
gmr.name = nickname;
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => list_users.Items.Add(gmr.name)));
SendUsersList(gmr.soc);
users.Add(gmr);
```

Nickname is defined here:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[gmr.soc.ReceiveBufferSize];
gmr.soc.Receive(buffer);
string cmd[] = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer).split('$');
string nickname = cmd[1]; //cmd[0] = 50 (means Register User by nickname)
Register(gmr, nickname);
```

The code of the client where it sends his nickname:

```
string text = "50$" + txt_nickname.Text;
byte[] data = new byte[Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(text)];
data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
socket_to_server.Send(data);
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. - You should provide sample of string which 'breaks' your loop

Comment: I'm sorry but this was my first question on stack overflow. I found out that the string contained "\0\0\0..." at the end and so I just had to replace it with ""